# Can’t sort elements to categories

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Im writing an online store, which is why I need the list of goods to be sorted in categories Eventually, the right path does generate, but there is no content on the page.
Where might I have made a mistake?

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'category'
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

        name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, verbose_name='Категория')
        slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='Транслит', null=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name

class Merchandise(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='Имя товара')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_images',default='default.jpg',verbose_name='Изображение')
    price = models.CharField(max_length=15,verbose_name='Цена')
    text = models.TextField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Описание')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Категория')
```

**views.py** 
There was a pagination function primarily

```
def category(reguest, slug):
    category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
    merch = Merchandise.objects.filter(category=category)
    return render(reguest, 'mainpage/category.html', {
        'category': category,
        'merch': merch})

def mainpage(request):
    data = {
            'goods': Merchandise.objects.all(),
            'slides': Slide.objects.all(),
            'categories': Category.objects.all(),
            'title': 'CyberGear'
    }
    return render(request,'mainpage/home.html',data)
```

**category.html**

```
{% extends 'mainpage/main.html' %}
{% for mer in merch %}
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="{{ mer.image.url }}" alt=""></a>
              <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">
              <a href="#">{{ mer.title }}</a>
            </h4>
            <h5>{{ mer.price }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ mer.text }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

{% endfor %}
```

**and urls.py**

```
url(r'^category/(<slug>)/$',views.category,name'category'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `urls.py` file as:

```
url('category/<slug:slug>/',views.category,name'category'),
```

you should include the **type**, alongside with the name of the variable.

Read more about them on the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't include your `Category` model attributes within `class Meta`.
Here's an Adjustment:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, verbose_name='Категория')
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='Транслит', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'category'
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'
```

- Also note: `class Meta` has no parentheses